Traefik IngressRoute. How to proxy a request to an external IP-address?
I use Traefik IngressRoute in Kubernetes.
My goal is to proxy a request when accessing https://kubernetes_host.com/my_api/... to http://10.139.158.30:5000/api/v1/
I would do this in Nginx:
location /my_api {
    proxy_pass http://10.139.158.30:5000/api/v1;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme http;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    
    }

But I can’t figure out how to do this in Traefik IngressRoute.
In the documentation, proxying requests only for internal Kubernetes services.
Example:
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: route-proxy
  namespace: xxx
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - xxx
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: PathPrefix(`/my_api`)
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: some-service
      port: 80


what is the 10.139.158.30 address? your internal node? This setup looks odd.

Hello. Yes, internal. Why it looks odd?
